# How to remove the caption bar of a window in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, frame

I would like to remove form frame in c#

Picture:
http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/9114/87017773.jpg

Anyone know how can I do this ?

Comment: For future reference, you can learn a lot by reading the manual: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form_properties.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WinForms you can set the `FormBorderStyle` property on the form to `None`.

Answer (score 2):

(I've added this as a second answer to make it clearer that Wallace actually got the right answer first. I had a couple of failed attempts!)

Set the `FormBorderStyle` property to `None`. Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Test
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Button button = new Button { Text = "Click to close" };
        Form form = new Form
        {
            Controls = { button },
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
        };
        button.Click += delegate { form.Close(); };

        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct on the FormBoarderStyle and good form in showing that you need to provide a button so the user can exit your app (other than Alt+F4 or other system menu actions). Bad form on the misleading button text ;)

Comment: @Tergiver: Text duly changed :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `Window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None` if you're using WPF.